# sftp net drive ssh server settings - get error 10058

Tags: sftp, net-sftp

I am trying out Eldos's SFTP Net Drive to map a drive to a virtual Ubuntu server. I works great when authenticating with a password. I have tried the normal/typical methods for configuring Key-based access. However, I receive error 10058. I have searched for clear instructions without success.

Anyone using this with Key-based access? Please share how you have it configured.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the server doesn't accept the key for whatever reason and closes connection. Usually this is an indicator of buggy server which normally should send the error packet in response.

But your question is offtopic here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. First, off topic? Where should this question be posted? Second, I have a clean VirtualBox running fresh/latest ubuntu server 12.04. I question buggy server as cause.

Comment: @LarryEitel not here, for sure. Maybe on SuperUser. And bugs don't depend on freshness - they are in developers' heads and their desire to create standard-compliant software. If the developer doesn't care, then software will ever be compliant, no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

If you're connecting via command line (e.g. using "open /profile:server" command line arguments) and you're accessing recently reinstalled server, the connection will silently fail because of changed server ssh fingerprint.

Try to reconnect manually (not using command line), accept new fingerprint and the problem will resolve.